# $this->_forward is not working while calling action using $this->view->action in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am calling an action using `$this->view->action` to get some response. Inside that action I am using `$this->_forward()`. however it does not work when I call it with `$this->view->action`.

I am calling:

```
$result = $this->view->action('search-results', 'controller', 'mobule', $requestParams);
```

Inside `searchResulsAction()` I am using

```
$this->_forward("get-listings", "controller", "module", $requestParams);
```

but call is not going to `getListingsAction()`

Answer (score 1):

First of and straight from the [Zend View Helpers documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action):

> Actions that result in a _forward() or redirect are considered invalid, and will return an empty string.

Second when you have `$this->view->action` you should be still inside a controller which means you should actually use `$this->_forward('search-results', 'controller', 'mobule', $requestParams)`. Unless you need to remain in that controller and view and don't want to end up in the `getListingsAction()` and view?

If you need to remain in that controller/view you should probably restructure your code by extracting those pieces from the other controller into Action Helpers or View Helpers. If in fact you like to end up in the getListingsAction then a forward is what you should do.